# What parameter type does bezierThrough in TweenMax library expect?

Tags: flash, actionscript, tween, gsap

I'm currently trying to adapt some sample code and have hit a snag when trying to replace hardcoded coordinates with a variable.

The following sample code works:

```
TweenMax.to(sp,
         5,
         {bezierThrough:[{x:250,y:100},{x:50,y:200},{x:500,y:200}],
         onUpdate:drawme,
              onUpdateParams:[sp]});
```

But when I try to replace the bezier points with a variable, I get a runtime error saying property 0 of Shape doesn't exist. sp is of type Shape. (Full error below).

```
 var centralLinePoints:Array = new Array();
  for (var i:int = 0; i < data.nodes.length; i++)
  {
      var foo:Object = data.nodes[i].data.abc;
      var bar:Number = data.nodes[i].data.def;
      if (foo != null)
      {
          centralLinePoints.push({x: bar, y: foo});
      }
   }

  TweenMax.to(sp,
5,
{bezierThrough:[centralLinePoints],
onUpdate:drawme,
onUpdateParams:[sp]});
```

I've found this documentation: http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/plugins/BezierThroughPlugin.html but I'm not sure what type is implied.

Full error:

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 0 not found on flash.display.Shape and there is no default value.
    at com.greensock.plugins::BezierPlugin/init()[C:[...]\greensock-as3\com\greensock\plugins\BezierPlugin.as:99]
    at com.greensock.plugins::BezierThroughPlugin/onInitTween()[C:[...]\greensock-as3\com\greensock\plugins\BezierThroughPlugin.as:68]

[sorry about the formatting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the third param to `TweenMax.to` you pass an object with 3 properties. The first is the `Array` of objects having `x` and `y` as properties.

Try to remove the square parenthesis:

```
TweenMax.to(
    sp,
    5,
    { 
        bezierThrough:centralLinePoints,
        onUpdate:drawme,
        onUpdateParams:[sp]
    }
);
```

Comment: ops, you did find it by yourself!

Comment: sorry! but do you know why I need square brackets around sp?

Comment: because it's an array of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've worked it out - apparently the square brackets around centralLinePoints must have been defining an array around my existing array or something of that nature. Taking them out fixed it. Not sure what the square brackets around sp do though...as I just get a basic Shape parameter to my drawme function.